# Replacing -inf values to np.nan in a feature pandas.series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, replace, series

I want to replace the -inf values in a pandas.series feature (column of my dataframe) to np.nan, but I could not make it.

I have tried:

```
    df[feature] = df[feature].replace(-np.infty, np.nan)
    df[feature] = df[feature].replace(-np.inf, np.nan)
    df[feature] = df[feature].replace('-inf', np.nan)
    df[feature] = df[feature].replace(float('-inf'), np.nan)
```

But it does not work. Any ideas how to replace these values?

Edit:

```
df[feature] =  df[feature].replace(-np.inf, np.nan)
```

works

BUT:

```
df =  df.replace(-np.inf, np.nan)
```

does not work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem may be that you are not assigning back to the original series.

Note that `pd.Series.replace` is *not* an in-place operation by default. The below code is a minimal example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'feature': [1, 2, -np.inf, 3, 4]})

df['feature'] = df['feature'].replace(-np.inf, np.nan)

print(df)

#    feature
# 0      1.0
# 1      2.0
# 2      NaN
# 3      3.0
# 4      4.0
```

Answer (score 23):

it should work:

```
df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
```