# Replace all inf, -inf values with NaN in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace, find, inf

I have a large dataframe with inf, -inf values in different columns. I want to replace all inf, -inf values with NaN

I can do so column by column. So this works:

```
df['column name'] = df['column name'].replace(np.inf, np.nan)
```

But my code to do so in one go across the dataframe does not.

```
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
```

The output does not replace the inf values

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### TL;DR

- [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) is fastest for replacing `±inf`
- **but** you can avoid replacing altogether by just setting [`mode.use_inf_as_na`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#available-options)

---

### Replacing `inf` and `-inf`

```py
df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
```

<sup>*Note that `inplace` is possible but [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020384/13138364) and will [soon be deprecated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529).*</sup>

[image]

Slower [`df.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) options:

- `df = df.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if x in [np.inf, -np.inf] else x)`
- `df = df.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if np.isinf(x) else x)`
- `df = df.applymap(lambda x: x if np.isfinite(x) else np.nan)`

---

### Setting [`mode.use_inf_as_na`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#available-options)

Note that we don't actually have to modify `df` at all. Setting [`mode.use_inf_as_na`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#available-options) will simply change the way `inf` and `-inf` are interpreted:

> `True` means treat `None`, `nan`, `-inf`, `inf` as null
> `False` means `None` and `nan` are null, but `inf`, `-inf` are not null (default)

- Either enable globally

  ```py
  pd.set_option('mode.use_inf_as_na', True)
  ```
- Or locally via context manager

  ```py
  with pd.option_context('mode.use_inf_as_na', True):
      ...
  ```

Comment: Use case: when I has set mode.use_inf_as_na I got error "ValueError: Input X contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')." from MinMaxScaler. After it I was back to df.replace().

Comment: `mode.use_inf_as_na` changes only representation of `np.inf` and `np.NINF`.
But under the hood it still stores them as `±inf`. So, if you want to get rid of them, you need to use replace().

Answer (score 6):

[`pandas.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) doesn't happen [in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49814077/replacing-inf-values-to-np-nan-in-a-feature-pandas-series).

So the problem with your code to replace the whole dataframe does not work because you need to assign it back or, add `inplace=True` as a parameter. That's also why your column by column works, because you are assigning it back to the column `df['column name'] =  ...`

Therefore, change `df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)` to either:

```
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan,inplace=True)
```

Or assign back to a new dataframe:

```
df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm...I am getting an TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' for both the choices that you gave.

Comment: Very strange, I am currently running it on my machine and it works. What pandas version are you using?

Comment: Version  - Python 3.8.0

Comment: and of pandas? ```pd. __version__``` ?

Comment: Pandas version: 1.0.1. I have 80 columns in the dataframe. Some non numeric.

Comment: I believe it has something to do with your pandas version. I use ```1.2.0```. Maybe it's time to update it :). I posted a picture in my answer to illustrate.