# Replace all inf, -inf values with NaN in a pandas dataframe if dtype backend is arrow instead of numpy

Tags: pandas, numpy, pyarrow

I was wondering if with the changes of pandas going forward from 2.0 to 3.0, the solution of using `replace` still applies if we don't know how +-Inf values are stored, i.e. their types. What is a robust solution here?

Link to the original solution assuming `numpy` dtype backend
[Replace all inf, -inf values with NaN in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66922511/replace-all-inf-inf-values-with-nan-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: have you tried using `replace`?